# Including combined output of Assetic in Template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, assetic

I'm writing an app using Symfony2, and I have a situation where I'd like to combine all CSS and Javascript resources and include them in my Twig template so that, in the end, there is only a single file returned via the HTTP request.

```
    {% block stylesheets %}
        {% stylesheets output='web/css/combined.css' combine=true 
            '@stylesheet1.css'
            '@stylesheet2.css'
            '@stylesheet3.css'
            '@stylesheet4.css'
        %}
        {% endstylesheets %}

        // PSEUDO

        include 'combined.css'

        // END PSEUDO
    {% endblock %}
```

So, instead of using Assetic to merely combine the files and then reference them, I want direct access to the output. All of the CSS would be in a single `<style>` tag and all the JS would be in a single `<script>` tag.

Is there a way to accomplish this without extending the existing libraries?

Comment: Why?! I ask because you can already access `stylesheetX.css` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want direct access to combined assets?

In fact, this is what assetic does: when in **dev** environment there is one `<style>` tag for each stylesheet, while in **prod** they are all combined in a single .css file and thus using a single `<style>`. The same happens for javascript files, fo course.

For the latter to work (in **prod** environment), you need to manually dump them:

```
php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod
```

Take a look at the source HTML weh in dev/prod. I've never used the `combine` option and there is [no official Symfony 2 documentation about it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html).